# How to send a google firebase User UUID with shopify's webhook after payment?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, shopify, webhooks, shopify-storefront-api

For a client's webshop I chose google's firestore database to authenticate users and keep track of their information. One of the properties on the associated user document is the order history. To add the products to their order history I need the google UUID to be send through a webhook, back to my node / express server. I used to do this with stripe with meta data. I tried to add the custom_attributes property to my checkout, but do not see this displayed in the order paid webhook response in my server. The question is, could anyone please help me find a way to get the UUID (google) from my (react) front end to my node / express back end through a webhook?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Any order booked by Shopify, has what are called **cart attributes**. In the act of setting up an order, why don't you store this UUID with the cart, as an attribute. It is just a key:value pair. When the order gets sent to your server, via a Shopify webhook, that info is embedded in the order, and easy for you to retrieve and use any way you want.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I will check it out!!^^